# How to add Geo Tag for wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

I am having website which are getting equal amount of traffic from UK and USA. Now I want to show different affiliate products for both countries. How can I do it ?

Comment: Check IP Geo locations

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use google analytics plugin for Wordpress. 
Here's a link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/